# Default (implicit) conversion (by splitting) from String to array in Groovy

Tags: arrays, string, groovy

Today one of my colleague shows me following lines of code in Groovy (I've checked it in Groovy Console 2.4.7):

```
String singleString = 'abcde'

String[] strings = singleString
println 'strings length: ' + strings.length
println 'strings class: ' + strings.getClass()
println 'strings[4] entry: ' + strings[4]
println ''

int[] ints = singleString
println 'ints length: ' + ints.length
println 'ints class: ' + ints.getClass()
println 'ints[4] entry ' + ints[4]
```

Result is:

```
strings length: 5
strings class: class [Ljava.lang.String;
strings[4] entry: e

ints length: 5
ints class: class [I
ints[4] entry 101
```

As you see:

- arrays are declared by type (not by `def` keyword),
- single `String` is split into every element of it and then it's converted (accordingly to `String` or `Integer`).

For the other hand for following code:

```
int singleInt = 12345
int[] intsFromInt = singleInt
println 'intsFromInt length: ' + intsFromInt.length
println 'intsFromInt class: ' + intsFromInt.getClass()
```

Result is

```
intsFromInt length: 1
intsFromInt class: class [I
```

I thought that it can be some type of [conversion](http://www.groovy-lang.org/differences.html#_conversions) but I don't see at this page any information about conversion to arrays.

So I'm curious:

- where I can find more information about this mechanism (splitting string into array)?
- how this mechanism is called?

Comment: Please look at [Coercion operator](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#groovy-operators) to see if that helps.

Comment: I would guess that it's based on how each type implements `asType(Class clazz)`. This is the method that is called when you execute `myObj as Type` which is another way to do type conversion in Groovy.

Comment: @Dónal as you see in above example there is no code like `as Type`. I understand that by declaring variable by type (for example `String variable`) conversion is done implicitly. Am I right?